# show that F is a gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Denoting $x{\bf{i}}+y{\bf{j}}+z{\bf{k}}$ by ${\bf{r}},$ let ${\bf{F}}({\bf{r}})=\|{\bf{r}}\|^2\;{\bf{r}}$. Show that ${\bf{F}}$ is a gradient vector and find $f$ such that $\nabla f={\bf{F}}$. 
Any idea how to solve this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every conservative vector field is also an irrotational vector field, so to prove that $\mathbf{F}$ is a gradient vector then you must show that: $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$

To find $f$ you do the integration: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = F_1$, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = F_2$, and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} = F_3$, where $\mathbf{F} = F_1\mathbf{i}+F_2\mathbf{j}+F_3\mathbf{k}$

Comment: That is true, but I wonder if there is an alternative way to show that F is gradient other than $\nabla X F=0$? 
@Navaro

Comment: No, You must show that Curl of F is 0